# Rails convention for loading classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conventions, autoload

I've been learning more about Rails and I'm familiar with the autoloading convention of:

```
A::B::C.new
```

would create a new type of C without having to require it because of the rails autoloading.

I could of course explicitly require `a/b/c` and it seems that is not really the "rails way".

I'm wondering if there are times in rails apps where it is more appropriate to use require explicitly as opposed to the autoloading. I could see with a deeply nested folder path how `A::B::C::D::E::F.new` for example could be a pain to type. Is it just the rails way to keep folder directories a small depth for this reason?

If anyone could shed some light on the rails conventions with this, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Requiring or not doesn't change needing to type A::B::C::D::E.new if that is the class name. Also plain require interacts badly with the development mode code reloading

Comment: Oh, good point about the A::B::C::D::E being needed. Sorry, I'm still making some of the analogies to java where folder structure is the class hierarchy, where that is not necessarily true in ruby.
Would there be a time to explicitly use require on your own code in Rails as opposed to letting rails autoload it based on the constant?